# Make TEX TIKZ FIGURE Symmetrical with Arrows

Tags: pdftex, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  main node/.style={draw}]
  \node[main node] (1) {A};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {B};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {C};
  \node[main node] (4) [below left of=3,xshift=1cm] {D};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]


     (2) edge [bend right] node [left] {} (4)
     (3) edge [bend left] node [left] {} (4)



\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

See how the Arrows going into D are not symmetric? How I can make them symmetrical and enter at the sides?

Comment: Do you also want to change the position of "D"?

Comment: @leandriis no thank you.

Comment: But then it's not symmetrical?

Comment: @leandriis thank you!! It is actually there are a few more nodes but I excluded them because it gets complicated. Basically there are  7

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the "symmetrical"  request correctly, but you can use `(4.east)` and `(4.west)` to make the arrow tips point to the sides of the "D"  box.

Answer (score 1):

Edges between nodes `n2` and `n4`, and `n3` and `n4` are symmetrical only in the case when node `n4` is horizontally middle of nodes `n2` and `n3`.  If it is not, than some symmetry can be only approximated, for example that connection point at node `n4` are symmetrical:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=22mm and 22mm,
every edge/.style = {draw, ->, shorten >=1pt},
       box/.style = {draw, minimum size=8mm, font=\sffamily\small},
                        ]
\node (n1) [box]                {A};
\node (n2) [box, right=of n1]   {B};
\node (n3) [box, right=of n2]   {C};
\node (n4) [box, below=of $(n2.south)!0.5!(n3.south)$]   {D};
%
\path   (n2) edge [bend right]  (n4)
        (n3) edge [bend  left]  (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=22mm and 22mm,
every edge/.style = {draw, ->, shorten >=1pt},
       box/.style = {draw, minimum size=8mm, font=\sffamily\small},
                        ]
\node (n1) [box]                {A};
\node (n2) [box, right=of n1]   {B};
\node (n3) [box, right=of n2]   {C};
\node (n4) [box, below right=22mm and 8 mm of n2.east]  {D};
%
\path   (n2) edge [bend right]  (n4.west)
        (n3) edge [bend  left]  (n4.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

result of the first image code example:

[image]

and result of the second example:

[image]

In image codes I change nodes name from 1, 2, 3 and 4 to n1, n2, n3 and n4.